# Node.JS and Express res.redirect() not enabling new webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to save a variable to a text file, but if the variable isn't found when using `spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()`, then I want my server to redirect to `app.get('/error', function(req, res) {});` which displays a different webpage, but it's returning the error:

> (node:11484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

How can I get around this error to display the webpage error.html?

I don't have access to EJS or `window.location` because it conflicts with other files and it's a node.js program, respectively.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'homepage.html'));
        try {
            spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
                .then(function (data) {
                    // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
                    client_cred_access_token = data.body['access_token'];
                    console.log(client_cred_access_token);
                    console.log('Client Credentials Success!');
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log('Something went wrong when retrieving an access token', err.message);
                    throw err;

                });
            fs.writeFile("./public/client_cred_token.txt", '', function (err) {
                console.log('Clearing previous access token');
            });
            fs.writeFile("./public/client_cred_token.txt", client_cred_access_token, function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
            });
            fs.readFile('./public/client_cred_token.txt', function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Saved Client Credentials as: %s", data)
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            res.redirect('/error');
        }
});
```

Key takeaway from the accepted answer is to not send any HTML/files to the server until it's confirmed which one is needed.

Comment: You are sending the html file first, therefore all headers are send, you have to move them at the end of the `try` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    try {

        spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant().then(function (data) {

            // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
            let client_cred_access_token = data.body['access_token'];
            console.log(client_cred_access_token);
            console.log('Client Credentials Success!');

            // truncate token file
            fs.truncateSync("./public/client_cred_token.txt");

            // write token to file
            fs.writeFileSync("./public/client_cred_token.txt", client_cred_access_token);

            // read token from file again
            // NOTE: you could use `client_cred_access_token` here
            let data = fs.readFileSync('./public/client_cred_token.txt');
            console.log("Saved Client Credentials as: %s", data)

            // send homepage to client when no error is thrown
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'homepage.html'));

        }, function (err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong when retrieving an access token', err.message);
            throw err;

        });

    } catch (err) {
        res.redirect('/error');
    }
});
```

I swapped all asynchron file opreations with the syncron one.
They throw an error and you dont have to deal with callback chain/flow.

Also i moved the `sendFile(...)` at the botom in the `try` block, so when a error is thrown from any syncrhonus function call the `sendFile` is not reached, and your redirect can be sent to the client.

Otherwise you would send the `homepage.html` to the client, with all headers, and a redirect is not possible.

Comment: Don't ever use `sync` versions of `fs` functions in a request handler in a server.   It ruins the scalability of the server as it blocks the entire event loop during every one of your synchronous fs operations.  Also, `throw err;` where you have it will do nothing useful.  It will not be caught by the `try/catch` because of the asynchronous callback you're in.

Comment: @jfriend00 The `throw err;` is fine, because from the promise catch function the error is relayed. Assume on the token store logic, it dosnt seems like the OP has more than 1 user

Comment: It's for a school project, not logistical server usage, so that's correct. I still had some parts of the error which I could fix with changing the catch (err) to just send the error.html instead, which is cleaner overall. Marc, very nice, concise, sensible answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @RhettJarvis - Well, if I were grading a server-based school assignment, I would ding it for using synchronous file I/O in a request handler.  It's not how anyone should learn to program request handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `res.sendFile()` first and then if you later get an error, you are also calling `res.redirect('/error')` which means you'll be trying to send two responses to one http request which triggers the error you see.  You can't do that.

The solution is to call `res.sendFile()` at the end of all your other operations so you can then call it when successful and call `res.redirect()` when there's an error and thus only call one or the other.

In a difference from the other answer here, I've shown you how to code this properly using asynchronous file I/O so the design could be used in a real server designed to serve the needs of more than one user.

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let data = await spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant();
        // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
        client_cred_access_token = data.body['access_token'];
        console.log(client_cred_access_token);
        console.log('Client Credentials Success!');
        await fsp.writeFile("./public/client_cred_token.txt", client_cred_access_token);
        let writtenData = await fsp.readFile('./public/client_cred_token.txt');
        console.log("Saved Client Credentials as: %s", writtenData);
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'homepage.html'));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/error');
    }
});
```